Use of snackbar as a widget
I want to use a Snackbar instead of the ErrorScreen for code as below. How is that possible?
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthSuccess) {
          return buildSuccessScreen(state);
        } else if (state is AuthError) {
          return ErrorScreen(state.message);
        } else if (state is AuthPrompt) {
          return _LoginForm(buildSuccessScreen);
        } else if (state is AuthEmailVerification) {
          return const VerifyEmail();
        } else {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}


You can have both builder and listener by using BlocConsumer instead of BlocBuilder. builder will be used to render widget based on the state, and listener will be used to trigger an action (the show snackbar method) on error state. Use listenWhen and buildWhen to control when to build and when to listen based on the current state.
return BlocConsumer<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
  listenWhen: (previous, current) {
    return current is AuthError;
  },
  listener: (context, state) {
    if (state is AuthError) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('Error message'),
      ));
    }
  },
  buildWhen: (previous, current) {
    // Only build when the state is not `AuthError`
    return current is! AuthError;
  },
  builder: (context, state) {
    // Notice that we remove `AuthError` case here
    if (state is AuthSuccess) {
      return buildSuccessScreen(state);
    } else if (state is AuthPrompt) {
      return _LoginForm(buildSuccessScreen);
    } else if (state is AuthEmailVerification) {
      return const VerifyEmail();
    } else {
      return const Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
    }
  },
);


Thank you! I want to display the actual error message on Snackbar. So when I use state.message inside the text, it is showing (state as invalid constant value as a build error).

If AuthState has the message property, you should be able to do that inside the if block since the type for state is inferred to be AuthError.

Got it. When my state is Autherror it displays the snack bar, but then immediately I want to go to my login form. It's not happening instead it is showing a circular progress indicator.

If the login form is a widget that can be shown directly in the current screen, add back the AuthError case on the if-else block inside the builder (as I removed it above), and remove the buildWhen condition. If the login form is on another screen that need to be pushed, call the navigator push method inside the listener just after showing the snackbar.
